# Can a husband and wife take Schengen visa appointments at separate centers?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens

My husband and I (both Indian citizens) are applying for a short-term Schengen visa to attend an academic workshop. We currently live in different cities (Bangalore, Mumbai). Is it possible (and advisable) to fill up a common online visa application form, but take appointments at separate visa application centers?

Making two completely independent applications might seem like we are trying to hide information as our flight tickets and some other documents mention both our names.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you both can't travel to the same appointment location?

Comment: @PeterM you mean, apart from living 1000km away from each other?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt If only there was someway you could get from one city to another in 90 minutes.

Comment: @Peter M If only there was some way we could get from one city to another in 90 minutes, cheaply, and without having to take a day's leave from work.

Comment: If you feel that consulates will negatively interpret an appointment in two different cities, you can both write an explanation in the covering letter stating that you are visiting with your spouse who has separately applied for visa at location Y (due to them being based there). Also as far as I am aware each individual has to fill a separate application form so I am not sure how a common online application will work.

Comment: @RedBaron, thanks a lot for your comment. That is a good suggestion.

Comment: I'll try and make it an answer so that other people may weigh in their opinions

Comment: @NehaKaranjkar I don't want to sound facetious, but I would expect that a day off work would be required anyway to attend an embassy appointment (every embassy I have had to attend has involved significant time) and that the cost of a discount ticket between cities would be a fraction of the overall budget of your Schengen trip.    And I would balance that against the actions of embassy staff who by definition are capricious.  Plus scheduling one appointment is easier than 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible (and advisable) to fill up a common online visa application form, but take appointments at separate visa application centers?

Each individual applying for Schengen visa has to make a separate application using the [designated form](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/application_form_english.pdf) (may vary slightly depending on the country involved), so to my mind the question of "common" online visa application form is moot. It is certainly possible for two individuals travelling together to apply at two different consulates if they are based in different cities.

Assuming that you and your husband are travelling to the same workshop and both of you will be attending it, both of you should fill the form and book VFS appointments based on your place of stay. Attach [all the supporting documents](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/4002758/Daten/3548239/business.pdf) (list based on German requirements but will vary depending on your destination country) with this form.

In the covering letter for this application, you can provide more details about your travel plans with regards to your spouse. Maybe something like:

> I would like to submit that I am attending this workshop with my spouse X. My spouse is currently based in Y and has therefore applied for short stay visa at your consulate in Y.

or a similar variation mentioning common tickets/hotel reservations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We used the approach suggested in this answer and everything worked out fine.